# Creating a POST request with X-Accel-Redirect with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, proxy

I'm using rails 4 and I'm proxying a GET request to another server like this:

```
def proxy_video(path)
  self.status = 200
  response.headers["X-Accel-Redirect"] = "/proxy/#{path}"
  render text: 'ok'
end
```

In my nginx config, I have this:

```
location ~* ^/proxy/(.*?)/(.*) {
    internal;
    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    # Compose download url
    set $download_host $1;
    set $download_url http://$download_host/$2;

    # Set download request headers
    proxy_set_header Host $download_host;

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying content to clients
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Stream the file back send to the browser
    proxy_pass $download_url?$args;
  }
```

This works fine for proxying GET requests like:

```
proxy_image('http://10.10.0.7:80/download?path=/20140407_120500_to_120559.mp4')
```

However, I want to proxy a request that passes a list of files that will not fit in a GET request. So I need to pass what currently goes in $args as POST data.

How would I proxy this POST data? - Do I need to do something like response.method = :post or something? - Where would I provide the parameters of what I'm POSTing?

Comment: X-Accel was actually much more flexible, allow POST requests etc, in older versions of nginx. I think around 1.9.x it was "fixed". I've been hunting for a way to do this too for the latest version, but for now I've been sticking to the old version and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this out-of-the-box with nginx. This feature is really designed for accelerating file downloads, so it's pretty focused on GET requests.

That said, you *might* be able to do something fancy with the lua module. After you've compiled a version of nginx that includes the module, something like this *might* work.

Ruby code:

```
def proxy_video(path)
  self.status = 200
  response.headers["X-Accel-Redirect"] = "/proxy/#{path}"
  response.headers["X-Accel-Post-Body"] = "var1=val1&var2=val2"
  render text: 'ok'
end
```

Nginx config:

```
location ~* ^/proxy/(.*?)/(.*) {
    internal;
    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    # Compose download url
    set $download_host $1;
    set $download_url http://$download_host/$2;

    rewrite_by_lua '
        ngx.req.set_method(ngx.HTTP_POST)
        ngx.req.set_body_data(ngx.header["X-Accel-Post-Body"])
        ';

    # Set download request headers
    proxy_set_header Host $download_host;

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying content to clients
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Stream the file back send to the browser
    proxy_pass $download_url?$args;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! - I will try it shortly and report back!

Comment: Waiting for your report @Hackeron ;-)

Comment: Actually I was able to proxy with X-Accel across all methods in Nginx 1.4.6, however this no longer works with 1.10.1. Trying to hunt down if this was a fix or an option though.

Comment: It does not work in Nginx 1.10.3. The ngx.header["X-Accel-Post-Body"] returns nil. So I am afraid that the header from RoR is not passed to the internal redirect?